# Material-ui Card Flip Animation

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

React Material-ui's documentation for their `Card` component states it *do not* flip over to reveal more information on the back. I don't understand why...but has anyone figured out a way to make them flip over using some other libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS Transition Group library, as follow.

1. In your CLI: npm install react-transition-group@1.x --save
2. In your React component, at the top import your new library:

```js
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'
```

Then in your return add:

```js
<CSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName="cardAnimation"
  transitionAppear={true}
  transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
  transitionEnter={false}
  transitionLeave={false}
>
  {
  // Your html content - probably your Card
  }
</CSSTransitionGroup>
```

3. Finally where you have your css style:

```css
.cardAnimation-appear {
      opacity: 0.01;
      transform: rotate(20deg);
    }

    .cardAnimation-appear.cardAnimation-appear-active {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 1s ease-in;
    }
```